# Как сделать высоту TableViewCell равной высоте CollectionView

Tags: swift

В Table View Cell у меня лежит вертикальный Collection View. Как мне сделать что бы высота cell была равна высоте Collection View и не обрезала его?

Answer (score 1):

- Если высота UICollectionView всегда одна и та же, то в IB(Interface
  Builder) можно задать высоту ячейки. Либо в коде указать rowHeight.
- Если высота UICollectionView
  всегда разная, то необходимо в делегате таблицы (UITableViewDelegate)
  возвращать корректную высоту для каждой ячейки таблицы [метод
  делегата](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview)

PS. Если используется autolayout для UITableViewCell, то можно использовать автоматический подсчет высоты. Для этого необходимо определить примерную высоту каждой ячейки и включать автоматический подсчет

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140 // примерная высота ячейки
```